# Uncaught TypeError: <function> is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am pretty new to Javascript and I've across an issue I can't seem to understand. The console is complaining saying it is not recognising the function.

I have the following code (GraphActions.js):

```js
var VentureDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/VentureDispatcher');
var GraphStoreConstants = require('../constants/GraphStoreConstants');
var StockService = require('../utils/StockService');

var GraphActions = {};

  GraphActions.getGraphData = function(request){
    //have the API call here.
    VentureDispatcher.handleViewAction({
      actionType: GraphStoreConstants.GET_GRAPH_DATA,
      data: request
    });
    StockService.getHistoricStockData(request);
  };

  GraphActions.recieveGraphData = function(response){
    VentureDispatcher.handleServerAction({
      actionType: GraphStoreConstants.GRAPH_DATA_RESPONSE,
      response: response
    });
  };

  GraphActions.test = function(){
    console.debug("found this.");
  };

module.exports = GraphActions;
```

And the following Javascript file which is calling the function within the code above:

```js
var request = require('superagent');
var GraphActions = require('../actions/GraphActions');

var StockService = {

  getHistoricStockData: function(symbol){
      request.post('http://localhost:8080/historicalData')
             .send({
                        "symbol":"GOOG",
                        "from":"2016-06-01",
                        "to":"2016-07-01"
                    })
             .set('Content-Type','application/json')
             .end(function(err,res){
               if(err || !res.ok){
                  console.error('Error making request!');
               }else {
                  console.debug(JSON.stringify(res.body));
                  GraphActions.recieveGraphData(res.body);
              }
            });
  }
};

module.exports = StockService;
```

The console is throwing the following error and not too sure why:
**venture-stock.js:44673 Uncaught TypeError: GraphActions.recieveGraphData is not a function.**

Does anyone understand why this is happening? The same method has been called in another place with no problem.

When debugging the code and evaluating GraphAction object in the above code I get the following where the functions defined above are not available:

[image]

Where as in another location, the functions are available:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess you're compiling your modules in a big js file. What do you use? Are you sure it's the same module? Do you have any circular references among the modules?

Comment: I'm using Webpack with a babel loader to compile the modules into one big js file.

And yes, both occasions I was importing the same module (i.e var GraphActions = require('../actions/GraphActions');).

I believe I don't have any circular references. A function (A) in GraphAction.js calls a function in StockService.js (B) which then calls a different function in GraphAction.js (C). I don't think this would count as a circular ref if they are calling different functions?

Comment: The point is that if any of the required modules in GraphAction has GraphAction in its dependency tree, the exported object will be temporary empty there. So yes, if everything is synchronous you'll have a problem. I'll set up an answer later.

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense. I've separated the actions that handle server responses into a separate file to come around this problem. Will accept your answer once complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because of a circular reference among your modules. The module `GraphActions` requires the module `StockService`, which *also* requires `GraphActions`. It doesn't matter if what's actually needed in `StockService` it's the `recieveGraphData` method, while the method that requires `StockService` is `getGraphData`: the module loader doesn't have this level of code analysis. `require` would always return the whole module, so it's a circular reference.

So, what happens in these cases?

The module loader, when loading `GraphActions`, meets `require('../utils/StockService')`, then *stops* the execution of `GraphActions` in order to load `StockService`. At this point, the exported properties of `GraphActions` are... none. So that's why in `StockService` you get an empty object.

### Solution A

Merge the two modules in one, e.g.

```
var GraphService = {
    getGraphData: function(request) {
        ...
        GraphService.getHistoricStockData(request);
    },
    recieveGraphData: function(response) { ... },
    getHistoricStockData: function(symbol) {
        ...
        GraphService.recieveGraphData(res.body);
    }
};
module.exports = GraphService;
```

### Solution B

It's the opposite, i.e. decouple `getGraphData` and `recieveGraphData` in two different modules. I don't really like this one, because it can lead to excessive module fragmentation.

### Solution C (recommended)

As long as CommonJS is used, you can take advantage of using `require` wherever you want, so in `StockService.js` you'd do:

```
getHistoricStockData: function(symbol) {
    request.post('http://localhost:8080/historicalData')
        ...
        .end(function(err, res) {
            ...
            var GraphActions = require('../actions/GraphActions');
            GraphActions.recieveGraphData(res.body);
        });
}
```

Now, since the execution will *not* immediately require `GraphActions`, the module will be loaded later when all its dependencies are fully loaded, so you'll get a fully working module.

### Differences with ES2015 modules

In ES6, you cannot use `import` outside the root level, i.e. you can't use `import` inside a function. So you couldn't use solution C with ES6 syntax?

Actually that wouldn't be necessary to begin with, because CommonJS module resolution is different than ES6's, the latter being more advanced. So, you'd have written:

```
import * as StockService from '../utils/StockService';
...
export function getGraphData(request) {
    ...
    StockService.getHistoricStockData(request);
};
export function recieveGraphData(response) { ... };
export function test() { ... };
```

and in `StockService.js`:

```
import * as GraphActions from '../actions/GraphActions';
...
export function getHistoricStockData(symbol) {
    request.post('http://localhost:8080/historicalData')
        .send( ... )
        .set('Content-Type','application/json')
        .end(function(err, res) {
             ...
             GraphActions.recieveGraphData(res.body);
        });
};
```

So what happens here? `GraphActions.js` is loaded, the `import` statement is reached, *the execution of the module stops* and then `StockService` is loaded. So far, it's the same as CommonJS.

In `StockService`, the loader would meet the `import` statement, then *the execution of `GraphActions` resumes* and the whole module is correctly exported. So **you'd be golden from the start with ES6.**

This will lead us to

### Solution D (most recommended... if you can)

Since you're already using Babel, use the plugin "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" or "preset-es2015" and use ES6 modules instead.

Hope this cleared your doubts!

(Btw, it's "receive", not "recieve" ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! -  ES6 is definitely something I will jump into next.